# Change Text Lable to Image in XCode

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have the following code in my XCode project for an iOS app I'm developing:

```
    testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    UIFont *Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:40];
    [testLabel setFont:Font];
    [testLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [testLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(float) 55/255 green:(float) 41/255 blue:(float) 133/255 alpha:1.0]];
    testLabel.text = @"Here We Go";
```

I am looking to put an image in that spot instead of the text. What do I need to replace this code with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you make an image and put it in an `UIImageView` or you make a `UIView` subclass in which you will draw the text inside the `drawRect` method.
In the second case, in your `drawRect` you do this :

```
[self.yourStringProperty drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100,150) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]]; 
or
[self.yourStringProperty drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
```

Also, look  [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for a detailed explanation of these functions which can also take into account the available width, minimum sizes, line breaks, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm more looking for what the exact code would look like though.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a bit more explanation. If you do a search for the `draw..` methods you should find a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above mine is the best with the second part:  use a UIView and put either your label or a UIImageView inside it depending on what you want.  Here's what it would look like with the image:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<<your image frame here>>)];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
image.frame = CGRectMake(<<your image frame here>>);
[container addSubview:image];
[self.view addSubview:container];
```